# Why using (or not) dedicated bridges with LXD?

Tags: networking, firewall, lxc, network-bridge, lxd

**Question: Are there specific drawbacks of using a single bridge, as opposed to a dedicated one per container?**

**Details**: I have a host which runs a few LXD containers. I initially decided to have one bridge per container, mostly to ease the firewalling between them, the host, the LAN and Internet. I therefore have several `10.10.1x.0/24` networks matching a `brx` bridge (where `x` is incremented for each container which gets a `10.10.1x.1` address and a default gateway of `10.10.1x.254` which is the bridge).

With the advent of [LXD2](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/lxd-2-0-introduction-to-lxd/) and its new bridge `lxdbr0` I started to wonder if it would not be better to move to a single bridge solution, with a `10.10.10.0/24` network, each of the containers getting its `10.10.10.y` IP, all of them routed though `10.10.10.254` (on the bridge).

My main consideration is separation of the containers and ease of administration of the firewalling.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons, I found out in the meantime, is that the bridge will be working at ISO/OSI layer 2 and therefore firewalling is much more difficult (it requires specific marking of traffic - with the source port/NIC).

Having separated bridges (and separated networks) makes firewalling more straightforward.